# Is there any config file etc in Android?

Tags: android

I have 3 apps whose base code is same but there are some features which I want to enable in some apps and disable remaining apps. I want to maintain flags to enable or disable those features for that I can create a boolean flags in some constants file but is there is any concept in android like having config file or something else from where I can edit those flags.?

Comment: you mean storing some file in the system for sharing across your applications?

Comment: no, these 3 apps are individual to each other. Before releasing these apps I will enable the flags, what all features need to be visible for that app that I will decide from that config file or something else.

Comment: ok, then. you can have the config properties within your code and load it as any other resource in any other java program, with `getResourceAsStream()`. The class `Properties` is still there, also.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am planning to do like this, I will add a json file which contains key, values, I will read from there. Is this correct appropach?

Comment: Properties are already native. When not in need of any complicated thing and just name value pairs... It comes with java

Comment: Use resources. [You can store there boolean values as well](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Bool).